# Lazy loading route path doesn't match properly

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have two parent components User Console and Shopping Cart.

The routes for them are locahost/user-console and localhost/shopping-cart.

Here are the routes file:

```
const UserConsoleRoutes: Routes = [
    {path:'', component:UserConsoleComponent, redirectTo:'my-profile', pathMatch:'full'},
    {path: 'my-messages',  component: MyMessagesComponent},
    {path: 'my-profile',  component: MyProfileComponent },
    {path: 'my-progress',  component: MyProgressComponent},
    {path: 'my-courses',   component: MyCoursesComponent},
    {path: 'my-receipts', component: MyReceiptsComponent},
    {path: 'my-credentials', component: MyCredentialsComponent},
    {path: 'group-membership',   component: GroupMembershipComponent}
];

export const UserConsoleRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(UserConsoleRoutes);
```

Shopping Cart Route:

```
const ShoppingCartRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component:ShoppingCartComponent, redirectTo:'cart', pathMatch:'full'},
    {path:'cart', component:CartComponent},
    {path:'profile', component:ProfileComponent},
    {path:'affiliation', component:AffiliationComponent},
    {path:'shipping', component:ShippingComponent},
    {path:'payment', component:PaymentComponent},
    {path:'confirm', component:ConfirmComponent},
    {path:'order-complete', component:OrderCompleteComponent},
];

export const ShoppingCartRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(ShoppingCartRoutes);
```

But whenever I go to shopping-cart it should redirect to shopping-cart/cart but it redirects to shopping-cart/my-profile

Here is my main app.routing.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: MainComponent},
    {path: 'user-register', loadChildren:'app/components/registration/registration.module#RegistrationModule'},
    {path: 'registration-confirmation', loadChildren:'app/components/registration-confirmation/registration-confirmation.module#RegistrationConfirmationModule'},
    {path: 'login', loadChildren:'app/components/login/login.module#LoginModule'},
    {path: 'shopping-cart', loadChildren:'app/components/shopping-cart/shopping-cart.module#ShoppingCartModule'},
    {path: 'my-console', loadChildren:'app/components/user-console/user-console.module#UserConsoleModule'},
    {path: 'product', loadChildren:'app/components/products/product.module#ProductModule'},
    {path: 'enrolment', loadChildren:'app/components/enrolment/enrolment.module#EnrolmentModule'},
    {path: 'admin-console', loadChildren:'app/components/admin-console/admin-console.module#AdminConsoleModule'},

export const routing:ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

I tried both pathMatch:'full' and pathMatch:'prefix'. I am not really sure where I am wrong.